# Dragging from 'more' popover in fullCalendar isn't working

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

Here's an example from the official web of Fullcalendar

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-dragging-resizing-demo

**RECREATING THE ERROR**

If you click the '+3 more' on March 13 the popover will open , then you have to drag the last event on the list ( which is Dinner at 8p ) and drop it on March 20 and it won't work .

So this is a general problem , I've used the fullcalendar's official for the sake of simplicity but it works on any escenario.

Do you have any sort of workaround for this situation ? , I really need to get that functionality .

Comment: It seems like an "error" with Fullcalendar itself. I see 2 options, either inform them about the problem, or you can just move it to the 19'th and then back to the 20'th.

Comment: interestingly it seems to be a problem for any event in the popover which is over the box for the 20th...so the 2.30pm event (or any above that) will work. I'd guess the fullCalendar code is mistakenly assuming that because the event's starting co-ordinates are already over the 20th, that it must have come _from_ the 20th and therefore you can't drag it there. Normally if you drop an event over its original day it just puts it back in its original position. But of course in this case the _real_ original position is in the popover, which is where it goes.

Comment: I'd tell you to raise a bug...and maybe you can still raise bugs for v3 and get them fixed. But it already appears to be fixed in v4 if you look at the demo for that version: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/event-dragging-resizing-demo . So maybe the best advice is just to wait for v4 to be released.

Comment: All going well v4 is due to be released on the 15th so you may not have long to wait, this was mentioned at the end of this blog post: https://fullcalendar.io/blog/2019/02/v4-beta-release